# Filtering out if the dictionary list has the key in a set

Tags: python, filter

```
events=[
    {'creator': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T07:00:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T07:30:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'},  'attendees': [{'email': 'b@hotmail.com', 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}, {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'organizer': True, 'self': True, 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}]},
    {'creator': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T07:30:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T08:00:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'attendees': [{'email': 'b@hotmail.com', 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}, {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'organizer': True, 'self': True, 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}]},
    {'creator': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2022-03-17T00:00:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2022-03-17T00:30:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}}
]
```

I would like to filter a dictionary list(slightly different list structure) if it has an ['attendee']['email'] that is valid(in emails) which is not the organizer. So ['attendees']['organizer'] can't be the one used.

```
emails=['b@hotmail.com'] 
for e in events:
    if e['attendees']['email'] in emails:
        print(e)
```

Produces

```
TypeError at /
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Should Output:

```
 {'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"1"', 'id': '1', 'status': 'confirmed', 'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=1', 'created': '2022-03-14T00:08:11.000Z', 'updated': '2022-03-14T00:08:12.162Z', 'summary': 'Appointment', 'description': 'Online appointment', 'location': 'Online', 'creator': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T07:00:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T07:30:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'iCalUID': '1@google.com', 'sequence': 0, 'attendees': [{'email': 'b@hotmail.com', 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}, {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'organizer': True, 'self': True, 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}], 'reminders': {'useDefault': False, 'overrides': [{'method': 'email', 'minutes': 1440}, {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}]}, 'eventType': 'default'},
 {'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"1"', 'id': '1', 'status': 'confirmed', 'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=1', 'created': '2022-03-14T00:08:11.000Z', 'updated': '2022-03-14T00:08:12.162Z', 'summary': 'Appointment', 'description': 'Online appointment', 'location': 'Online', 'creator': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T07:30:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2022-03-15T08:00:00-0700', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'iCalUID': '1@google.com', 'sequence': 0, 'attendees': [{'email': 'b@hotmail.com', 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}, {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'organizer': True, 'self': True, 'responseStatus': 'needsAction'}], 'reminders': {'useDefault': False, 'overrides': [{'method': 'email', 'minutes': 1440}, {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}]}, 'eventType': 'default'}
```

Comment: Please consider editing this question so the code samples don't have syntax errors (the first example produces `SyntaxError: unmatched ']'`). Also, there is no reason to include all these fields in the dicts…they just make the question hard to read and are not relevant.

Comment: `e['attendees']` is a list you can't do `e['attendees']['email']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e['attendees'] is a list so you need to specify it's index

```
for e in events:
    try:
        if e['attendees'][0]['email'] in emails:
            print(e)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: Is there a way to index the one without organizer. So something like 0 as a dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Your third entry does not contain a 'attendees' field. your 3rd line of code will fail due to this.

If I understand you correctly, you only want to print out events that contain an attendee who's email is contained in the 'emails' list. If this is true, this code will work for you (Assuming having no attendees is a legitimate case):

```
for e in events:
    isValid = True
    if e.__contains__("attendees"):
        for a in e["attendees"]:
            if a["email"] in emails:
                print(e)
```

Comment: It's more like check if it has an attendees without an organizer.